# How to implement a generic class that conforms one of the mutually associated protocols?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I have two protocols. Each (**x**) of them contains `associatedtype` that requires to confirm another protocol (**y**) when `associatedtype` of this protocol (**y**) equals `Self` (of **x**).

```swift
protocol B {
    associatedtype AA: A
        where AA.BB == Self
}

protocol A {
    associatedtype BB: B
        where BB.AA == Self
}
```

It is no problem to implement those protocols as follows:

```swift
class AAA: A {
    typealias BB = BBB
}

class BBB: B {
    typealias AA = AAA
}
```

But I can't implement one of them as generic.

```swift
class AAA<BBBB: B>: A {
    typealias BB = BBBB
}

class BBB: B {
    typealias AA = AAA<BBB>
}
```

As a result, I have an error:

> 'A' requires the types 'AAA' and 'BBBB.AA' be equivalent

And note:

> requirement specified as 'Self' == 'Self.BB.AA' [with Self = AAA]

Sounds understandable. I added the constraint to my generic class.

```swift
class AAA<BBBB: B>: A where BBBB.AA == AAA {
    typealias BB = BBBB
}
```

And result

> error: type 'AAA' does not conform to protocol 'A'
> note: protocol requires nested type 'BB'; do you want to add it?
>
> error: type 'BBB' does not conform to protocol 'B'
> note: protocol requires nested type 'AA'; do you want to add it?

All my tries to solve it was unsuccessful, they just changed error messages.
Is it possible to do? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my current knowledge, I don't think it's possible to do what you want.
I was looking for more information and I found some of them  about why it's not needed.

[Why Swift doesn't have F-Bounded](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/2c6p0o/why_doesnt_swift_have_fbounded_quantification/).

[Support for F-bounded polymorphism?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6446)